# Account Id field not available in 'Standard Fields' list of Contacts

Tags: duplicate-management

I have a requirement where we need to prevent Duplicate Contacts. The criteria should be based on First Name, last Name and Account id. I am trying to implement 'Duplicate management' functionality.

Account is related to Contact on a Look up relationship. Account Name is available in Standard Fields list and we enter it in UI. But Account Id is not available in Standard Field list. So it's not available to pick when I create 'Duplicate Rules'. But it's available to pick in 'Validation Rules', I am not sure how. Does anyone has any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Use a duplicate rule on Account to prevent duplicate Account Names, Then, your duplicate rule on Contact can use `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Account Name`

**Solution 2 (if duplicate account names are OK)**

Matching rules can't use formula fields so you'll need a custom field on Contact of type Text: `AccountId__c`

Populate `AccountId__c` with a before insert/update trigger.  Note that duplicate rules do not run after workflow field updates so you need a trigger here.

Then, your matching rule can use `First Name`, `Last Name`, and `AccountId__c`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But yes Account Names can be duplicate since unique key is combination of Name and Symbol. So if I go as per your 2nd solution, are you sure triggers will be fired before Duplicate Rules?

Comment: The second solution works as I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: Triggers are definitely fired before duplicate rules; as a kindness to the Community, mark the answer as the solution or, if it is not  the solution, indicate why not in a comment.

Comment: Now after implementing your solution, i wanted to populate this custom field with the value of a formula field. SInce in production, i need to update for thousands of records, can you suggest the best way to populate the field value other than using any App.

Comment: This is really a new question and should be posed as such but why not Data Loader?

Comment: Thanks,  i was thinking to use simple SOQL query to do that but in Production need to go for Batch apex or something. But yeah Data Loader is only best option.