# Duplicate rules not triggering

Tags: duplicate-management

Currently I am trying to prevent contacts with the matching first and last names from being assigned to the same Account. Currently on contact I have an custom Account Id field on contact that's updated via a workflow rule.

My active matching rule looks like the following:

```
(Contact: Account_Id EXACT MatchBlank = FALSE) AND (Contact: FirstName EXACT MatchBlank = FALSE) AND (Contact: LastName EXACT MatchBlank = FALSE)
```

My duplicate rule has the following settings:

- Bypass sharing
- Block on update
- Block on edit
- No conditions
- Active
- The matching rule mentioned earlier

I'm unsure of why it's not blocking the creation. At first I thought it was because ([according to documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)) workflow rules trigger after Duplication rule checks are made but I ensured those fields were populated and tested it again.

For example:

We have John Smith assigned to Generic LLC. I should be able to add Alex Smith, John Brown, Alex Brown, etc. But I shouldn't be able to add another John Smith to Generic LLC. I should be able to add John Smith to Other Company Inc. but there can't be two contacts with the same first and last name assigned to one account.

Note: When using the Contact object for matching rules this is an example of what the options will look like.

[image: Duplicate Management look]

Currently the only issue I'm experiencing is if I create an account that has the same first and last name as an inactive account and is associated with the same account the new contact is not blocked. New / updated Active Contact with existing duplicate Active contact does block.

As suggested I have created a trigger that looks like the following:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after delete, after insert, after undelete, 
after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore && !Trigger.isDelete){
        for(Contact c : trigger.new){
            if(c.RecordTypeId == RecordTypes__c.getValues('Inactive Contacts').Id__c){
                c.Account_Id__c= c.AccountMap__c;
            }
            else{c.Account_Id__c = c.AccountId;}
        }
    }
}
```

AccountMap is the same thing as AccountId but it's done in a custom field so Inactive contacts don't show up on the account page.

Trouble shooting tip: Sometimes turning off and on duplicate rules fixes things.

Comment: So you're wanting to disallow a contact with same first & last name but unique contactId's and accountId's from being assigned to the same Account? If being assigned to the same account, at the time of assignment, the AccountId's would presumably be unique from one another until *after* the update occurred wouldn't they? Perhaps you could provide a specific case example (with values) of what you're trying to prevent?

Comment: @crmprogdev Added an example. Hope that helps.

Comment: Where does the field `Account_Id` come from? Is that on Contact? it's not `Contact.AccountId` is it?

Comment: @crmprogdev Account_Id__c is a custom field on contact

Comment: @Griffin How is the Account_Id__c field populated? Why not just use the Contact.AccountId?

Comment: @Fernando Sadly it's not an available field. Although Account_Id__c is populated through a workflow rule

Comment: And is the workflow field update reevaluation checkbox marked?

Comment: @Fernando Yup. I had hoped that was a fix too

Comment: @FernandoGavinho Don't give up on me here man!

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/115212/2602

Comment: Psssh that's a duplicate of my question.

Comment: But seriously that question didn't pop up anywhere. Google, even when I was making the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is possible, but not the way you're trying. I see only one option:

- Instead of a workflow, use a before trigger to make the change on the `Account_Id` field.

Also, mind that duplicate rules are only evaluated if the *watched fields* are evaluated, and that can cause trouble on the testing as well.

Comment: This was one of my first ideas but it was shot down by product owner, QA, and other devs really fast because Account name isn't always unique. If account name holds the Id instead of the actual name i will accept this. I'm not sure how to test this however

Comment: If you go to **Setup > Customize > Contact > Fields** you'll see that the Account Name has the API name _Account_ and is a reference (Lookup) to Account. Reference fields always hold the Id.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the watched fields?

Comment: If your matching rules _watches_ the FirstName, LastName and AccountId fields. The duplicate rules will only fire if you make changes to one of those fields (not sure if this is on the docs, but It happened on my tests)

Comment: At a code level I know you're right but when it comes to Salesforce Config and picklist values Account Name tends to be the actual account name. Like in merge fields on email templates the field isn't the Id but the actual account.

Comment: If you use an **<apex:outputField>** with a reference field (wich holds the Id) salesforce will also display the Name. A quick way to test it, is to create your rule using the Account Name and then create two accounts with the same name and see if the duplicate rules block contacts with the same name on different accounts. I'm can't test it right now, but I'll run some tests later to confirm that.

Comment: Yeah I'm about to run that test.

Comment: I have bad bad news. I just tested it and Account Name is the actual name of the account not the Id. :( I was hoping man. I was hoping big time.

Comment: Yeah. you're stuck with the trigger than. [This question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115174/account-id-field-not-available-in-standard-fields-list-of-contacts) presents the exact same problem.

Comment: @Frenando Not going to be your favorite person here but I just tried it and while the field is populating off the trigger correctly it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43022/discussion-between-fernando-gavinho-and-griffin).